# (Node J.S.) SyntaxError: Unexpected token function on an async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

So I'm trying to use async/await but i get this error:

```
async function something(options) {
  ^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token function
```

Here's the code:

```
var request = require('superagent');

async function something(options) {
    let response = await request.get("apiurlblabla");
    if(response) {
      .query(({'queryqeureur}))
      .query(({'uqeryqery'}))
      var jsonString = JSON.parse(res.text)
      console.log(jsonString.propertyblabla);
      console.log(jsonString.propertyblabla)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your node up to date? Async/await got enabled in node 7 I think.

Comment: oh shit bro im on 6.10

Comment: You still have syntax errors on top of having a wrong version.

Comment: and what are the errors?

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/37815790/2969544

Answer (score 7, accepted):

async function is supported officially in nodejs 8 and later. you should update your nodejs version to 8 or later.

Answer (score 1):

Install node version manager:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.6/install.sh | bash
```

Install new version of node:

```
nvm install 8.0
```

Update verion which uses:

```
nvm use 8.0
```