# Firebase Cloud functions deployment error

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have been using firebase cloud functions for some time now and did a minor bug fix today in my code and got the following error when tried to deploy. I undid that change and tried to deploy again with the last committed stable change, but still the same error. Any solutions?
PS: This is a typescript project and I compile it with tsc.

`Deployment error.
Function load error: Code in file lib/index.js can't be loaded.
Is there a syntax error in your code?
Detailed stack trace: /user_code/node_modules/request/node_modules/sntp/lib/index.js:19
exports.time = async function (options = {}) {
                     ^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token function`

Comment: what node version are you using?

Comment: I just started having the same issue as of today. Friday everything worked fine. My node version is v6.11.5 and npm 3.10.10

Comment: the same error as above @sashok_bg?

Comment: does it matter? as in it gets deployed in firebase which runs in node 6+ something I guess. Typescript compilation works.
My node version however is 8.5.0

Comment: Exactly the same but using gcloud instead of firebase

Comment: probably another issue like the one we had a couple of days back with firebase cloud functions?

Comment: I asked because of this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43789298/7015400 (but it seems you have the right node version)

Comment: I disagree about node version. The documentation says that gcloud uses 6.11.5 https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/

Comment: however, npm run serve works without an issue.

Comment: and i switched to another firebase project, and deployed the exact same code, it got deployed. But the project at question gives the above error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I manually went to GCP and deleted the cloud functions and deployed again and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same kind of error.
In my case, changing Node version to 8 fixed this error.

https://medium.com/google-cloud/migrating-firebase-cloud-functions-to-node-8-aebdb0d3d9a9

```
Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Code in file index.js can't be loaded.
Is there a syntax error in your code?
Detailed stack trace: /user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/logging/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/index.js:28
async function request(opts) {
      ^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token function
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/logging/node_modules/gtoken/build/src/index.js:18:18)
```

Comment: For the sake of time, According to the documentation, to use a Node 6 runtime you need to use a firebase-admin version lower than 8.0.0 and a firebase-functions version lower than 3.0.0. But just change to Node 8, since Node 6 will soon not be supported, and Node 10 is atill in beta on GCP. Link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_runtime_options

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message using gcloud beta functions with serverless framework https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/google/.

I resolved my problem by deleting the local .serverless folder and updating the version of https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/datastore to the latest and running npm install

Answer (score 0):

I've been facing the same problem but with another library called `request`. In your case is `sntp` library.

The problem is because the update of library version using `async wait` which is not supported.

The solution in my case is downgrade the library version in `package.json` (remove '^' sign) and then run `npm install` again in functions folder.