# Wrong NodeJS Version Running in Expo

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo

I am trying to call `async function _signInWithGoogleAsync()`
but I keep receiving a syntax error. I know that my node version must be greater than 7.6 for async functions to work as stated from this post: [SyntaxError: Unexpected token function - Async Await Nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37815790/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-function-async-await-nodejs)

But when I updated my node version to 8.4.0, and ran `async function _signInWithGoogleAsync()` I kept getting the same error. I think expo might be building an older version of node but I don't think that's likely because I've taken this auth function directly from their website: https://github.com/expo/expo-docs/blob/master/versions/v25.0.0/sdk/google.md

Comment: I should also mention that in order for me to build the starter app I had to fix many functions that were not recognized by my version of node.

Comment: I've also tried ```console.log(process.version)``` to see if the code that is running is less than 7.6 but the ```.version``` attribute doesn't exist. Instead, the ```process``` object has been replaced by : 
```Object {
  "env": Object {
    "NODE_ENV": "development",
  },```

Comment: Can you share error log of console which you were getting

Comment: ```SyntaxError in /home/splacorn/Desktop/collect-my-data/screens/HomeScreen.js: /home/splacorn/Desktop/collect-my-data/screens/HomeScreen.js: Unexpected token, expected ( (74:17)

ABI25_0_0RCTFBQuickPerformanceLoggerConfigureHooks
ABI26_0_0RCTFBQuickPerformanceLoggerConfigureHooks
<redacted>
<redacted>
<redacted>
<redacted>
<redacted>
CFRunLoopRunSpecific
GSEventRunModal
UIApplicationMain
Exponent
<redacted>```