# NodeJS Syntax issue

Tags: node.js, chromium

I'm having a problem with my node JS code, i'm getting the error:

```
/root/dev/remote/remote.js:43
.on('connection', async (socket) => {
                        ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:611:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:160:9)
Launching Chromium
[486:527:0824/012248.628260:ERROR:bus.cc(394)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")

(google-chrome:486): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: 01:22:49.591: Unable to get session bus: Unknown or unsupported transport ?disabled? for address ?disabled:?
[486:610:0824/012250.491318:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(619)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get: object_path= /org/freedesktop/UPower: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.UPower was not provided by any .service files
[486:610:0824/012250.493116:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(619)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.UPower.GetDisplayDevice: object_path= /org/freedesktop/UPower: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.UPower was not provided by any .service files
[486:610:0824/012250.497596:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(619)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.UPower.EnumerateDevices: object_path= /org/freedesktop/UPower: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.UPower was not provided by any .service files
^C[509:509:0824/012302.391101:ERROR:x11_util.cc(109)] X IO error received (X server probably went away)
[486:486:0824/012302.391250:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_x11.cc(62)] X IO error received (X server probably went away)
```

However, the syntax to this is perfectly fine.

I've tried reinstalling node/using different versions but im not sure if it's something to do with that in the first place.

here's the remote.js (there's more, this is just the relevant area)

```
const server = require('http').createServer();
const socketIO = io(server);

socketIO
.on('connection', async (socket) => {
    socket
    .use((socket, next) => {
        if(true) return null;
        if(socket.handshake.query && socket.handshake.query.token){
            jwt.verify(socket.handshake.query.token, 'SECRET_KEY', (err, decoded) => {
                if (err) return next(new Error('Authentication error'));
                socket.decoded = decoded;
                next();
            });
        }else{
            next(new Error('Authentication error'));
        }
    })
```

Does anyone know what this is? im trying to display my chromium instance on my Centos 7 VPS into a browser and control it through browser.

Comment: What version of node.js?  That error looks like an older version that doesn't know about either `async` or fat arrow functions.  You could try removing both (replace with classic function) and see if that gets you by that error.

Comment: @jfriend00 im on node v6.17.1 ill try that now, but i don't think that will fix it :(

Comment: @jfriend00 i just realized my node is severely outdated, thanks to centos. Going to try to update or figure out how.

Comment: I don't think node.js v6 supports `async` without special command line flags.  Definitely worth getting a much, much newer version of node.js if you want to use modern language features.

Comment: @jfriend00 you're right! Thank you :) I updated and all errors gone! Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SyntaxError: Unexpected token function - Async Await Nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37815790/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-function-async-await-nodejs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your older node v6.17 won't support the `async` keyword by default (ES7 feature).  There is a command line switch that might enable some of the newer features, but honestly that version is a bit old.

Since node.js is now up to v12 for a stable release, you probably want to upgrade to a newer node.js version if you want to use the most recent language features.