# "Parsing Error: unexpected token function" on Async Function with a recent Node version

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, npm

I am working on a side project, using node and firebase.

I can create regular functions and cloud functions, but when I try to create an async one like this :

```
 async function getApartments(){...}
```

I have this error :  "ESLint: Parsing error: Unexpected token function"

I saw on others posts ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37815872/9224397)) this can be linked to using Async functions on an old version of node, but since I'm on a recent version of node (17.8) I really don't understand the problem.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> [mcve]

Comment: The title tells a different story then the body. Which error is the correct one?

Comment: @Andreas I don't understand how the title tells a different error ? The error is about the function token, and I found it can be due to an async function on older versions, which is not my case, hence my question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good morning,
Do you use eslint ?
if yes ->

```
{
"parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2017 @see https://eslint.org/docs/latest/user-guide/configuring/language-options
}
```

Comment: Hello ! Yes I do. This that, had to add a few rules (missing jsdoc for example) but it worked like a charm. Thank you!